# How do I filter "BOOTP/DHCP, Request" out in tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

There are a lot of "BOOTP/DHCP, Request" in tcpdump and I would like to filter it out.

It's easy to filter arp out.

```
tcpdump -nni eth0 not arp
```

What about `BOOTP/DHCP, Request`?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work

```
$ sudo tcpdump -nni eth0 not bootp
tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error
                                                                                                                
$ sudo tcpdump -nni eth0 not dhcp
tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error
                                                                                                               
$ sudo tcpdump -nni eth0 not dhcpd
tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error
```

What is the right tcpdump for this?

Comment: Try `'not (udp port 67 or udp port 68)'`.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

In tcpdump, the "nickname" for the port of the protocol "BOOTP/DHCP" is `bootps`. For instance, to filter for only DHCP packets:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 port bootps
```

Or to exclude them:

```
sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 not port bootps
```

### Details

As a tip, to get the "nickname" for a given port/protocol, check the file `/etc/services`:

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep bootp
bootps      67/udp
bootpc      68/udp
```

Note that `bootps` is used for the server port, and `bootpc` for the client port.

Although technically speaking one may think we must use both (e.g. `tcpdump -n -i eth0 port bootps or bootpc`), the fact is that every DHCP packet with use the port 67 at source or destination (some packets will have src port 67 and dst port 68, while others src port 68 and dst port 67). So just filtering by `port bootps` usually works.